# To pass an email address to outlook from an AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, email, air

Is it possible to pass an email address to outlook from an AIR application???? 
My adobe air application has to send email address and the message content also.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the URL Syntax for sending an email; and open it up in a [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) along with [navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29). Something like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello&Body=SomeText");
navigateToURL(request);
```

This basically, passes the request onto the operating system who will handle it.  There is no way to guarantee that outlook will be the default email client opened up.  I haven't done this in years, so if memory serves me not all mail clients support the 'body' attribute to prepopulate the emails body text.

Comment: just remember to URL encode subject and body (`some%20great%20stuff%20goes%20here`)